# Highlight Changes in the same Column in new Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as such -

```
| ID   | Status | Data          | Column |
|:----:|:------:|:-------------:|:-------|
| 1    | A      | Old           |111     |
| 2    | B      | Old           |222     |
| 3    | C      | Old           |333     |
| 2    | C      | New           |222     |
| 3    | D      | New           |333     |
| 1    | E      | New           |111     |
| 4    | E      | New           |444     |
| 4    | E      | Old           |444     |
```

I want the output to highlight changes based on ID and Data like this , this should be regardless of IDs and Data columns position in row as given in sample above.

So, the result should look like this -

```
| ID   | Change Status | Data          | Final Status| Column | 
|:----:|:-------------:|:-------------:|:-----------:|:------:|
| 1    | A    -> E     | New           | E           | 111    | 
| 2    | B    -> C     | New           | C           | 222    |
| 3    | C    -> D     | New           | D           | 333    |
| 4    | No Change     | New           | E           | 444    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pivot this dataframe to get the changes:

```
df = df.pivot(index=['ID', 'Column'], columns='Data', values='Status').reset_index()

    Data  ID  Column New Old
0      1     111   E   A
1      2     222   C   B
2      3     333   D   C
3      4     444   E   E
```

You can then add in the other bits to adjust this into the desired format.

To get the `'Change Status'` column, you can use numpy's select, which will assign a different value if the old and new columns match or not, as below:

```
values = [df['Old'] + ' -> ' + df['New'], 'No Change']
conditions = [df['New'] != df['Old'], df['New'] == df['Old']]
df['Change Status'] = np.select(conditions, values)

    Data  ID  Column New Old Change Status
0      1     111   E   A        A -> E
1      2     222   C   B        B -> C
2      3     333   D   C        C -> D
3      4     444   E   E     No Change
```

Then the `'Data'` column is just populated with 'New', so this can be done using:

```
df['Data'] = 'New'

    Data  ID  Column New Old Change Status Data
0      1     111   E   A        A -> E  New
1      2     222   C   B        B -> C  New
2      3     333   D   C        C -> D  New
3      4     444   E   E     No Change  New
```

The `'Final Status'` column is just the `'New'` column, so you can rename this:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'New':'Final Status'})

    Data  ID  Column Final Status Old Change Status Data
0      1     111            E   A        A -> E  New
1      2     222            C   B        B -> C  New
2      3     333            D   C        C -> D  New
3      4     444            E   E     No Change  New
```

Now you can just select the columns you want, in the order above:

```
df = df[['ID', 'Change Status', 'Data', 'Final Status', 'Column']]

    
    Data  ID Change Status Data Final Status  Column
0      1        A -> E  New            E     111
1      2        B -> C  New            C     222
2      3        C -> D  New            D     333
3      4     No Change  New            E     444
```

(If you want ID to be a column not an index, you can just use `.reset_index()`)

Comment: Thanks, this works, but how can I maintain other columns in Dataframe if they exist?

Comment: @DJKarma It would depend on what they looked like and how you would want that data to be kept.  In your example, you wanted to go from 8 to 4 rows, and I don't know how/what data in the other columns you'd want to keep when reducing those rows. Perhaps add an example extra column to your questiton, and how you'd want this kept in the output and I can have a look?

Comment: So it will have same entries always depending upon the ID, as edited.

Comment: If it depends on the ID, then it can be passed into the index argument in pivot as a list :) I will update my answer

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can split the data by grouping them and then merge them together.

```py
(idx1, grp1), (idx2, grp2) = df.groupby('Data')

out = grp2[['ID', 'Status']].merge(grp1, on='ID', suffixes=['_Change', '_Final'])
print(out)
```

```
   ID Status_Change Status_Final Data  Column
0   1             A            E  New     111
1   2             B            C  New     222
2   3             C            D  New     333
3   4             E            E  New     444
```

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer with the new input data. The code stays the same.